# Set default value for xsd:element in the xsd file

Tags: python, xsd

I'm useing generation data structures from XML Schema. There is a part of xsd file, which descibe TCPInterface class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="tcpinterface_xsd.xsd" 
            xmlns:cext="tcpinterface_xsd.xsd" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" 
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xsd:element name="TCPInterface">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="port" type="xsd:integer"/>
....
```

How i can set a default value for "port" element in this xsd file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the attribute default="{yourInteger}" to the element. See an example below :

```
    <xsd:element name="port" type="xsd:integer" default="2"/>
```

Note that, in this case, if your port element is empty before validation, the XML Infoset change after validation and become the post schema validation infoset (PSVI) with the default value assigned to port element.

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsd:element name="port" type="xsd:integer" default="1" />
```